# Is there a multi-line string syntax in Netlogo?

Tags: string, syntax, netlogo

In Python there is a way to store long, multi-line text into a variable like so:

```py
    a_string = """
          This is a very long string
          that spans multiple lines
          and I do not need to worry about
          line breaks
    """
```

My question: Is there a similar thing in **NetLogo** where I can just encase a block of text into special characters and store into a variable? Any alternative ways, such as string concatenation will work too, like so:

```py
a_string = "This is a very long string"
           + "and I might need to use some regexes"
           + "to get it into this format\n"
           + "as long as it's possible to do so."
```

So far I could not find anything like the former example, have not really searched for the latter as the former is my preference, but would appreciate any other alternatives.

Comment: The `word` primitive should do what you want, just use it with parenthesis for multiple values, `(word "This is a very long string"\n  "and I might need..."\n  "...do so.")`.  See the docs for more:  https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#word

Comment: This is a great option! Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it. Otherwise, I  will reproduce this comment with credit to you as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`word` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#word) should be able to do what you want.  Just make sure to surround it with parentheses to handle multiple values.  Example:

```
to set-a-string
  let a_string (word "This is a very long string"
           "and I might need to use some regexes"
           "to get it into this format\n"
           "as long as it's possible to do so.")
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!